# How does gmail query from 900 million records? with rdms or no-sql?

Tags: sql, database, performance, gmail, hotmail

According to this [Techcrunch news](http://techcrunch.com/2015/05/28/gmail-now-has-900m-active-users-75-on-mobile/?ncid=rss)

Gmail has 900 million users. When I try to login with my username and password to gmail, It queries with the speed of light. Do they use rdms (relational) or no-sql? Is it possible with rdms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't exactly how it's done, but one billion records at say 50 bytes per user name is only 50 gigabytes. They could keep it all in RAM in a sorted tree and just search the sorted tree.

A binary tree of that size is only thirty nodes deep, which would take microseconds to traverse, and I suspect they'd use something that branches more than a binary tree so it would be even flatter.

All in all, there's probably much more amazing things google does, this part is relatively trivial.